# Chat Highlight Bug

Tags: bug, chat

[image]

Using @ will ping and highlight a username, however @@ will ping and not highlight the name.

Comment: @@SterlingArcher this is annoying because when I quick scan to see who pinged me I cannot see it.

Comment: Why would you use @@? You might consider this a feature: ping without highlight. That is, trollping.

Comment: By the way, if you click on the "number of pings" icon on your avatar in the chat window, does it jump to the given line? Does it keep count of that in the first place?

Comment: It does pop up with the number. And nobody double @s on purpose. It's just a bug is all. I doubt it has any attention to it.

Comment: Apparently I get pings even if I don't want them http://i.imgur.com/0JKzOAs.png

Comment: @VarunAgw that's an unrelated thing. Chat pings anybody with var contained in their name if they've been in the chat recently.

Comment: While we're at it, let's remove 3 letter pings

Comment: actually chat pings with minimal names. @Ster would likely ping you